# Update bound control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm learning WPF. I figured out how to bind to a list box using the following code.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Name="lstUpdates" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryData}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Loaded="lstUpdates_Loaded">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="46" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**CS**

```
public class HistoryRow
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ArticleUpdateId { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<HistoryRow> HistoryData { get; set; }

DataContext = this;
HistoryData = new List<HistoryRow>
{
    new HistoryRow { Header = "10/29/1961", Description = "Blah blah" },
    new HistoryRow { Header = "12/2/1976", Description = "Blah blah" },
    new HistoryRow { Header = "5/24/1992", Description = "Blah blah" },
    new HistoryRow { Header = "2/18/2012", Description = "Blah blah" },
};
```

I've got this so it works pretty well. But now my question is how can I refresh my listbox when my data changes. I've found several "solutions" on the Web and none of them work for me.

Comment: Are `HistoryData` of type `ObservableCollection`? What kind of solution didn't work for you?

Comment: http://www.wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html You will need NotifyOfPropertyChange

Comment: @Fabio: Since I don't know what is `ObservableCollection`, should I assume the answer is no?

Comment: Just replace List<HistoryRow> to ObservableCollection<HistoryRow> - that's all

Comment: @cdmnk: what if my data is coming from LINQ? How to convert it to `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: `new ObservableCollection(yourLINQ.ToList())`

Comment: @cdmnk: Hmm... Doesn't seem to work for me. So, I populate it as you suggested. And when my data changes, I populate it the same way again (with the new data). Should I do something different?

Comment: Now you have 2 answers, and this is two possible and reasonable ways :) choose by yourself

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My solution: Don't use binding. Just populate the list by creating a collection and assigning it to the `ItemsSource` property. Then, when the data has changed, do it again.

I don't know why WPF has to make so many things a pain, but when it's difficult to get a clear answer on stackoverflow on how to refresh the list, or I'm looking into reading a bunch of articles for such a simple task, it's probably a good indication I'm on the wrong track.

Perhaps I will find a reason to get into MVVM design and binding. But for now, all I want to do is update my ListBox.

Comment: Your problems *are* the reason you should start with MVVM (the pattern, not any framework). WPF was made with MVVM in mind, if you do it any other way, you will be *fighting* WPF every step of your journey.

Comment: That may be. But it took me a minute to manually populate the thing without binding and I don't seem to be having any issues with this approach. I'm open to hearing about how my approach is bad. But so far, it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: The only "bad" thing about your approach is that you are doing Windows Forms with a fancy looking base window. Once you do more complicated things, where WPF is really more powerful than Windows Forms, if you do it the old way, you will wonder why people think WPF is great. To get any advantage over WinForms, you will need to embrace the WPF way of doing it. There are plenty of tutorials, the two answers are pretty good already.

Comment: @nvoigt: Yes, and I expect I will study it. But today I just want to refresh my ListBox.

Comment: Your problem is that you binding your "business" logic to the UI logic. Based on your solution I assume you not testing your application. If you need to run whole application only for testing some feature - you are not testing you are debugging and it is take more time than testing automatically.

Comment: @Fabio: Given my stated objective simply to update my listbox, that isn't a problem. Either way, I appreciate you addressing the question. But if you must use symbols I have no idea what they are and you are not able to respond to me when I ask you what they are, obviously, the approach being described is pretty involved and is not aligned with my current objective.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inform a view about changes of your collection.
When using `ObservableCollection` as source of `ListBox` control, the view listening a event `CollectionChanges` and update control when event get raised.

So change type of `HistoryData` to `ObservableCollection<YourHistoryDataType>`

To work properly you need keep same instance of collection and update only items.

To keep same instance create a property on your viewmodel:

```
private ObservableCollection<HistoryRow> _HistoryData;

public ObservableCollection<HistoryRow> HistoryData 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return _HistoryData;
    }
    set 
    {
         If(Equals(_HistoryData, value) return;
        _HistoryData = value; 
        this.OnPropertyChange(nameof(this.HistoryData);
    }
}
```

Calling `OnPropertyChanged` will inform view about that instance of collection was changed.

Read this: [Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx)
There are some information about `ObservableCollection` and `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. So, I populate it by creating a `ObservableCollection<>` from my LINQ results. And when my data changes, I populate it the same way again (with the new data). Should I do something different?

Comment: What is `OnPropertyChange`?

Answer (score 1):

Your class HistoryRow will need to extend INotifyOfPropertyChange,

Then instead of using an Ienumerable, it needs to be of type ObservableCollection and subscribe to PropertyChangeEvent

```
private ObservableCollection<HistoryRow> _historyData;
public ObservableCollection<HistoryRow> HistoryData 
{ 
    get {return _historyData}
    set {_historyData = value; OnPropertyChange("HistoryData");}
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: `HistoryData` don't need to extend `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: HistoryData = collection1; HistoryData = collection2 - this will need propertychanged to work properly

Comment: What is `PropertyChanged` here?

Comment: Try public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

Comment: Your ViewModel will need to extend INotifyPropertyChanged, not your class.